# windows does not properly handle * (asterisk) argument when passed to python script

Tags: python

I have a python script handling conversion of FIX (xml/json type) data.
However under windows the argument * does not work to select all files for processing.
However it does work under bash windows.
Any way to circumvent/address this behavior?

Comment: This sounds like it has nothing to do with Python, and everything to do with your expectation of how the environment (`bash` vs `cmd`?) from which you *run* your script behaves.

Comment: This code is not properly formatted. Please [edit] to fix it. If needed, refer to [code formatting help](/editing-help#code). But more importantly, what do you mean by "does not work"? That is, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Oh actually, I think I get what you're saying. The problem you're probably experiencing is that CMD doesn't do file wildcards, which has nothing to do with Python. Check out these questions: [Is there any way to get the windows cmd shell to expand wildcard paths? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/460598/443564), [Filename globbing Windows vs. Unix](/q/11557280/4518341)

Comment: but cmd works with other commands. like for example if i do a copy * that works or a del * or move *. all of these work

Answer (score 0):

As it seems windows cannot handle wildcards on it's own for file expansion. The individual binaries like copy, move etc handle on their own.
The solution here is to add a loop to pass on each filename to the script:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.log) DO convert_FIX.py %%i
```